# Error parsing XML: not well formed(invalid token)

Tags: android, eclipse, parsing

I am new to java programming and am strictly following one tutorial right now.  I got pretty far into it until something happened that I just can't fix.  I searched google and looked at the code over and over and did not see anything wrong.  Here's a screenshot of my code....nvm I am not allowed to post pictures because I'm new so here is the code copied. The first X says Error parsing XML: not well formed(invalid token) and the second X says XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.  I appreciate all the help, thanks.

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
< LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myMessage"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:text="@string/answer" 
        />

< LinearLayout--------1st X is located here. The < is not spaced in the code but spaced here because that was the only way i could put it here
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="red" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="green" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="blue" />

< LinearLayout >---------2nd X is located here. The < is not spaced in the code but spaced here because that was the only way i could put it here and there is a / in between < and LinearLayout
```

Comment: complete the xml code. its incomplete

Answer (score 1):

xml is not structured well... below is the corrected one.
there should not be a space between < LinearLayout & this tag is not closed properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myMessage"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:text="@string/answer" 
    />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="red" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="green" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#0000ff"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="blue" />

</LinearLayout >
</LinearLayout >
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss one close tag `</LinearLayout>` at bottom. Here the working one `

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myMessage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/answer" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="red"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="green"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="blue"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot allow to give space between open tag and tag name. Give linear layout tag without space like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
```

This is wrong

```
< LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Answer (score 0):

remove spaces from `<LinearLayout` tags .use `<LinearLayout` instead of `< LinearLayou` as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myMessage"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:text="@string/answer" 
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="red" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="green" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="blue" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```